# Help! Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to conenct to socket/com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection Refused

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6.

I noticed yesterday the Dropbox automation stopped working.

I am now getting the following error message:

*Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket/com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection Refused*

Does anybody know why this would happen and how I can fix it?